# Scraping node with specific text using scrapy and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I don't understand why the below doesn't work. I know there are related answers, but they didn't help me.

```
$ scrapy shell "http://edition.cnn.com"
```

There is an `h2` tag with "CNN Money" as text inside. Why doesn't the below work?

```
>>> response.xpath('//h2[contains(string(), "CNN Money")]')
[]
```

I also tried `text()`

```
>>> response.xpath('//h2[contains(text(), "CNN Money")]')
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about XPath expression you use. The problem is that the page content is supplied dynamically e.g. by some JavaScript. Check yourself -- try to search for *CNN Money* in the page source code. You won't find any hit. You need to render the page and parse the output. I suggest you use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) together with [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) library for that purpose.

**EDIT:**

Run Splash using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8050:8050 --restart=always scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 3600
```

It increases the maximum timeout for requests. (You can look at [documentation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-run-splash-in-production) about other options how to run Splash in production.) You also need to increase the `timeout` field in `args` parameter to `SplashRequest`, e.g.

```
yield scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.json', args={'timeout': 3600})
```

Comment: I managed to get Splash working, thanks! Had to use the IP address shown when I start docker instead of the IP address in the tutorial. I need to learn more about Splash now, because the rendered HTML Splash gives me looks like a total mess and I don't understand how I can find the items I want to scrape.

Comment: @Andras It might look like a mess, because Splash doesn't fetch all stuff by default, but you should be able to get all the elements the same way as you see them when inspecting the page via other browsers' tools (Firefox, Chrome).

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand! This video was also helpful: [Scraping JavaScript pages with Scrapy and Splash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvFC93vAB7U)